# Add grid over 3D surface using persp3D (plot3D package)

Tags: r, plot3d

I'm trying to add a grid on top of a 3D surface created with `persp3D` (package `plot3D`), however I can't sort a way of doing it without causing a deformation on the grid.

```
library(plot3D)
data("volcano")
```

`volcano` is a 3D matrix that can be used to create a 3D plot by simply calling:

```
persp3D(z=volcano)
```

What I intend to do is create a new grid using the dimensions of the 3D matrix and than add it to the 3D plot.

```
# new grid
x.seq <- seq(1, dim(volcano)[1], length = 20)
y.seq <- seq(1, dim(volcano)[2], length = 20)

# Visualize grid
plot(x=c(0,length(volcano[,1])), y=c(0,length(volcano[1,])), type='n')
abline(v=x.seq, h=y.seq)
```

I got close to it by subsetting the matrix `volcano` by the new sequences created and then plot the new 3D matrix over the original 3D surface.

```
# New matrix using sequences created
mtx.sub <- volcano[time.seq, freq.seq]

# Plot new matrix on top of original surface
persp3D(z=volcano)
persp3D(z=amp.sub, border="black", facets=NA, add=T, colkey=list(plot=F))
```

[image: 3D plot with overlaid grid]

Even though the result is close to what I expected, a closer look will show that the grid is not really on top of the existing surface, it is a whole new surface that do not match the original one (which is quite obvious, given that it is a different matrix).

What I'm looking for is a way to add a 2D grid that will go over the original surface, something similar to `abline`, but for a 3D plot.

I had a look at `plot3D` documentation and searched on the web, but none of the solutions apply to `persp3D()`.

Any thoughts on a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the grid directly within the call to `persp3D`:

```
persp3D(z=volcano, border="black", lwd=0.3)
```

[image]

In response to your comment, you could plot at lower resolution to get wider borders, however, the surface will also be at lower resolution (see below). It would be nice to be able to plot the surface at full resolution and then have a sparser net of border lines that still matches the high-resolution surface, for example, by plotting the border lines only on every other facet, but I'm not sure how to do that without hacking `persp3D` (or one of the functions called by `persp3D`).

```
persp3D(z=volcano[seq(1,nrow(volcano),2), seq(1,ncol(volcano),2)], 
        border="black", lwd=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that is the grid from the original matrix. I'm looking for a way to plot a subsetted grid, with "larger" cells

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to use `ribbon3D`. It requires some more lines of code and messing around with parameters, but it does work reasonable.

[image: example]

```
require(plot3D)

### create data from 3D plotting
###
### x1, x2 a grid
### x the value of a normal distribution
x1 <- seq(-4,4,0.025)
x2 <- seq(-4,4,0.025)
mu = 0
z <- matrix(rep(0,length(x1)*length(x2)),length(x1))
for (i in 1:length(x1)) {
  for(j in 1:length(x2)) {
    z[i,j] <- dnorm(x1[i],mu,1)*dnorm(x2[j],mu,1)
  }
}

### plot 3D
sel = 1+c(1:32)*10  ### selection of the grid lines to plot
persp3D(x1,x2,z, 
        border = NA, facets = TRUE, col = rgb(1,1,1,0.5), 
        theta = 30, phi = 30, 
        zlim = c(0,0.26))
ribbon3D(x1[sel],x2,z[sel,], 
         border = NA, facets  = NA, col = 1, width = 0.02,
         along = "y", space = 0.9, add = TRUE)
ribbon3D(x1[],x2[sel],z[,sel], 
         border = NA, facets  = NA, col = 1, width = 0.02,
         along = "x", space = 0.9, add = TRUE)
```

Example with the volcano data

[image: example with volcano]

```
require(plot3D)

### create data from 3D plotting
x <- 1:length(volcano[,1])
y <- 1:length(volcano[1,])
z <- volcano

### plot 3D
selx = seq(1,max(x),4)
sely = seq(1,max(y),4)
persp3D(x,y,z, 
        border = NA, facets = TRUE, lwd = 0.03,
        theta = 30, phi = 30)
ribbon3D(x[selx],y,z[selx,], 
         border = 1, facets  = 1, col = 1, width = 0.1,
         along = "y", space = 0.9, add = TRUE)
ribbon3D(x[],y[sely],z[,sely], 
         border = 1, facets  = 1, col = 1, width = 0.1,
         along = "x", space = 0.9, add = TRUE)
```